# Find Caller User Inside Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

How to find out which oracle logged in user has called the stored procedure inside the stored procedure itself. I tried CURRENT_USER but failed.

The questions on stackoverflow are related to sql server. I am looking specific to oracle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `USER` function.  Or `SYS_CONTEXT( 'USERENV', 'SESSION_USER' )`.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the `STANDARD.USER()` function will produce a SQL statement, including the potentially expensive PL/SQL to SQL context switch, so the `SYS_CONTEXT` should be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Simply reference the pseudo-column USER:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure sp as
  2  v_user varchar2(32) := USER;
  3  begin
  4  dbms_output.put_line(v_user);
  5  end;
  6  /

Procedure created.

SQL> begin sp; end;
  2  /
THEUSER

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Better use the accepted answer's `SYS_CONTEXT` approach, as that will not incur [an expensive PL/SQL to SQL context switch](https://blog.jooq.org/2018/09/07/beware-of-hidden-pl-sql-to-sql-context-switches/)